# change Model property object type during modelbinding

Tags: .net, model-binding

I have a class as below:

```
class A{ //my main model
public int A {get;set;}
public object obj {get;set;} //declared as object
}

class B{public string BB {get;set;}}
class C{public string CC {get;set;}}
```

I declared "object" because I have one view with different model. During the model binding event, i was able to change the "object" type to the appropriate object. The problem I am facing is the object couldn't obtain its properties values(i.e BB=null)

```
protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {
        if (propertyDescriptor.Name == "obj")
        {
            string productType = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("GenericModelType").AttemptedValue;
            Type instantiationType = Type.GetType(productType);
            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(instantiationType);
            propertyDescriptor.SetValue(bindingContext.Model, obj);
            return obj;
        }
        base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know that each object can be binded to a modelbinder. Here's what I did to resolve my issue:

```
public class ObjectModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ValueProvider.ContainsPrefix("GenericModelType"))
        {
            //get the model type
            var typeName = (string)bindingContext
                .ValueProvider
                .GetValue("GenericModelType")
                .ConvertTo(typeof(string));
            var modelType = Type.GetType(typeName);

            //tell the binder to use it
            bindingContext.ModelMetadata =
                ModelMetadataProviders
                .Current
                .GetMetadataForType(null, modelType);
        }
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

What happens here is during the modelbinding event, It will first try to bind my main model(A) and it detected a "list" property. Since my model defined "list" as an object, It will try to bind create object type. However, I already setup a modelbinder for "object" type. So it used my custom binder which does what I needed to do.